# JavaScript with PHP for the onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

While submitting my form which will not validating. I am using submit for form submission and I have to redirect my page. By using `onclick` event it should be validated..

```
<td id="main">
  <h2>Add Info </h2>
  <form action="create_info.php" name="f1" method="post">
    <p>Info Title:
      <input type="text" name="menu" value="" id="menu" />
    </p>
    <p>Position:
      <select name="position">
        <?php
        $info_set = get_all_info();
        $info_count = mysql_num_rows($info_set);
        for($count=1; $count <=$info_count+1; $count++){
        echo " <option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>Visible:
      <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" />NO
      <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" />YES
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="validateForm()"/>
  </form>
  <br>
  <a href="content.php">Cancel</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script language="text/java script">
  function validateForm()
  {
    if(f1.menu.value== "")
    {
      alert("name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The `language` attribute of the `script` element has been deprecated long ago. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead. And where are you defining `f1`?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel No need to even do that as it is the default script in all modern browsers.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995: Correct, but it should be defined if the OP uses HTML 4.01 or XHTML (in order to validate).

Answer (score 0):

It didn't validate because you havn't block the submit event. You should put your validation in onsubmit event, it will be triggered when you click the submit button.

Working code in jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FHZKr/

```
<form action="create_info.php" name="f1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <p>Info Title:
    <input type="text" name="menu" value="" id="menu" />
    </p>
    <p>Position:
        <select name="position">
         <?php
         $info_set = get_all_info();
         $info_count = mysql_num_rows($info_set);
         for($count=1; $count <=$info_count+1; $count++){
         echo " <option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";
         }
         ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Visible:
     <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" />NO 
     <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" />YES
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm()
{
  if(f1.menu.value== "")
  {
      alert("name must be filled out");
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oops...there is typo in previous version. Try it. Updated the script tag from `language="text/java script"` to `type="text/javascript"`